# In R_Shiny, How to integrate an "animated gif" using renderImage with the "download report" example

Tags: shiny, animated-gif

I would like to:

1. Click a Button to "Generate Report"
2. Start an animated gif, showing "Computing ..."
3. Begin long computation using an Rmd file that generates and downloads an HTML report and
4. Stop the animated gif.

I can do both independently but not in the desired sequence. Need help. Here is my code in two files:

Shiny code

```
library(shiny)
library(here)
here::here()


ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("How to intgrate an animated gif using renderImage with download report example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
    ),
     mainPanel(
        imageOutput("myImage")  # this is a placeholder for image
     )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$myImage <- renderImage({
        
        outfile = here::here("www", "Computing2.gif")
        # write(outfile, "outfiledup.gif")
        # outfiledup =   here::here("outfiledup.gif")
        # outfiledup
        # 
        
        # Return a list containing the filename
        list(src = outfile,
             contentType = 'image/gif',
             width = 125,
             height = 50,
             alt = "This is alternate text")
    },  deleteFile = FALSE) # TRUE)
    
  
  
  
  
  input_file = "report.Rmd"
  output_file = "report.html"
  
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = output_file, # "report.html", default filename of downloaded file
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), input_file) # "report.Rmd")
      file.copy(input_file, tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      # params <- list(n = input$slider)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

here is my report.Rmd file.

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "ABC DEF"
date: "Aug, 2022"
output: html_document
---
params:
n: = NA

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Comment: Looks like I am having difficulty posting an Rmd code snippet because of back ticks. This link gives a simple report.rmd file https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html It should be adequate for test purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Here is my animated gif file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kPixNDI9V2SS3a8FYEwIl1yBEX0fVQGu/view?usp=sharing